# name of this exercise

Tags: dumbbells

I search for the name of this exercices :
*(I am very strong in drawings)*
[image]

1. the arm is against the body with the dumbbell in suspension
2. keep the elbow glued to the body and raise the forearm
3. we finish the movement with the dumbbell aligned to our arm, one weight on the shoulder the other pointing in front, the elbow pointing in front

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a Hammer Curl as per the list [here](https://www.issaonline.com/blog/index.cfm/2020/12-biceps-curl-variations-to-keep-your-arms-engaged).

> This bicep curl variation is like the standard biceps curl with one small adjustment. Turn the palms towards the midline of the body with the thumbs up. Curl the weight up towards the shoulder creating flexion only at the elbow. Extend the elbow and lower the weight back to the starting position.
>
> The rotation of the palms adds a focus on the brachialis and brachioradialis in a way that many other variations cannot.

[How-To Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwD-YGVP4Bk)

Adding the elbow floating away turns it into a "cheat curl" variation. Here, the "cheat" is not necessarily meant pejoratively. It just means that, by letting the elbow move, you're recruiting other muscles, such as the deltoids in your back, which reduces the biceps isolation, but will allow you to lift more weight, which can translate to a bump in your ability to lift heavier weight in a "strict" hammer curl.

Comment: Indeed it is the same movement but in the end we end up on the shoulder. Thanks

Comment: @Hadock: Ah, so in Step 3, the elbow becomes "unglued"? Does that happen after you've reached the full range of motion in Step 2 and the weight is resting on your shoulder?

Comment: at the same time as the movement goes from 2 to 3, I did not specify but then we had to do another exercise, an STO

Comment: @Hadock: Truthfully, that sounds like a "cheat curl" where you allow the elbow to float out so that you can recruit your back muscles into the curl. It's called a "cheat" because you're not strictly isolating the muscles, but it's considered good practice for allowing you to lift more weight than usual, which will translate into a bump with the "strict" curl.

Comment: ok I understand thanks a lot :)